# How to get the count of rows prior a specific date with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like the following:

```
    start_date  finish_date
0   2020-06-01  2020-06-02
1   2020-06-02  2020-06-04
2   2020-06-03  NaT
3   2020-06-04  2020-06-07
4   2020-06-05  2020-06-07
5   2020-06-06  NaT
6   2020-06-07  NaT
```

which can be re-created using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': ['2020-06-01', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-04', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06', '2020-06-07'],
    'finish_date': ['2020-06-02', '2020-06-04', pd.NA, '2020-06-07', '2020-06-07', pd.NA, pd.NA],
})
df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['finish_date'] = df['finish_date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

**The question is**: how to get the count of rows which have no `finish_date` or not yet finished by the `reporting_date`, the following is the expected result:

```
    reporting_date  not_finished
0   2020-06-01      1
1   2020-06-02      1
2   2020-06-03      2
3   2020-06-04      2
4   2020-06-05      3
5   2020-06-06      4
6   2020-06-07      3
```

To explain the expected result above:

(when I say row, I refer to the row in the dataset not the result)

- By `reporting_date` `2020-06-01`, the row `0` has started but not finished, that counts `1`.
- By `reporting_date` `2020-06-02`, the row `0` has already finished and row `1` has started but not finished yet, that counts `1`.
- By `reporting_date` `2020-06-03`, the rows `1` and `2` have started but not finished yet, that counts `2`.
- By `reporting_date` `2020-06-04`, the row `2` has already finished and rows `2` and `3` have started but not finished yet, that counts `2`.
- and so on..

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got column `not_finished`

Comment: @Erfan I explained the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehesion to compare each `reporting_date` to previous values of `finish_date`. To handle `NaT`, you need to `fillna` it by `pd.Timestamp.max`

```
s = df.finish_date.fillna(pd.Timestamp.max)
df['not_finished'] = [(x < s.loc[:i]).sum()  for i, x in enumerate(df.start_date)]

Out[35]:
  start_date finish_date  not_finished
0 2020-06-01  2020-06-02             1
1 2020-06-02  2020-06-04             1
2 2020-06-03         NaT             2
3 2020-06-04  2020-06-07             2
4 2020-06-05  2020-06-07             3
5 2020-06-06         NaT             4
6 2020-06-07         NaT             3
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `s.iloc[:i+1]` to ensure slicing of string type or unsorted index will work

Answer (score 1):

```
def fn():
    d, open_dates = (yield), []
    while True:
        open_dates = [od for od in open_dates + [d.finish_date] if od is pd.NaT or od > d.start_date]
        d = yield len(open_dates)

f = fn();next(f)
df['not_finished'] = df.apply(lambda x: f.send(x), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  start_date finish_date  not_finished
0 2020-06-01  2020-06-02             1
1 2020-06-02  2020-06-04             1
2 2020-06-03         NaT             2
3 2020-06-04  2020-06-07             2
4 2020-06-05  2020-06-07             3
5 2020-06-06         NaT             4
6 2020-06-07         NaT             3
```

Comment: Thanks! it's a clever answer but when applied on real data, it took a very long time.